# How can I use one Python program to turn another one into an exe file?

Tags: python, automation

So for example, I have a file called turn.py, how can I use turn.py to turn another file called main.py into main.exe as soon as turn.py is executed?
Please answer as it will really really help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: use pyinstaller

Comment: pyinstaller is used as:

Go to the directory where the python file is located in the command prompt and type in pyinstaller filename.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install PyInstaller from PyPI:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Go to your program’s directory and run:

```
pyinstaller test.py
```

This will generate the bundle in a subdirectory called dist.

reference this: [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

**[edit]**

you can also put this command in your code, this is a demo:

[image]

[image]

run `turn.py`, you will get a folder called `dist` and `main.exe` is there:

[image]

Comment: On typing "pyinstaller myFile.py" in cmd, or using os.system(), it says" 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. " even though I have it installed with latest version of pip.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean by "the same..."

Comment: use pip list to check if you've installed the pyinstaller module in the right location, also i edit my answer about code in .py file

Comment: I checked. It says Pyinstaller is in version 3.6; I am however, using Pythyon version 3.8. Can this be the problem? Cuz it still says that pyinstaller is not a command. :C

Comment: different version is ok, make sure pyinstaller is installed in your current interprter and what's your tool? pycharm or vscode? if possible, show me your error screenshot

Comment: like the demo shows, i create a virtual environment called .venv, so i select it as my current interpreter and install pyinstaller by command pip install pyinstaller in terminal